# create a notification/alert at a specific time html css angular

Tags: html, css, angular

i created a notification box that it shows me an alert when i create a notification from the date which i create this notification.

but i want now to add a new feature "start from" or something else, to be this notification active in this time.

For Example: i created the notification in 14:00 but it should appears **automatically** at **14:30**.

how can i do it ? which technic should i do to make it?

thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Could you please provide some code on stackblitz.com to enable us to test what you're looking for?

Comment: Did you try to do it with JS? you can create a timer function and can activate the notification by force when the time's up. If you want to add a time that the notification will be active, you can send your desired value (taken by an input field) to the timer function and assign it as your notification time.

Answer (score 0):

look into `setTimeout()`. It lets you execute a function after an interval in milliseconds. For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
// show notification after half an hour
}, 30 * 60 * 1000)
```